# Would incrementing the min cut edges by 1 increase the max flow by 1 as well?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, max-flow

Given the theorem that max flow <= min cut,
Would incrementing the min cut edges by 1 increase the max flow by 1 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the theorem that max flow **=** min cut, that would indeed be the case (if all capacities are integers).

*If* you make *all* min-cuts larger. There may be more than one.

To be clear: if you increase the capacity of *all* edges in *all* min-cuts, the max-flow may increase by more than one. At least one (assuming integer capacities), but then yet another cut may be minimal.

If you increase the capacity of each min-cut by one, the max-flow increases by one (again assuming integer capacities).